# Custom linux kernel: mount needs EXT4 probe explicitly

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, mount, ext4

I have a customized linux kernel with version **2.6.32**.
When i boot the kernel it boots perfectly fine but I can't figure out why mount gives this error?

```
mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/mydrive/
EXT3 fs (sda1): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
mount: bad fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1.
missing codepage or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg: tail or so
```

but when i fire following command it worked fine

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /tmp/mydrive/
```

My partitions are

**/boot** is on sda1 with filesystem **ext4**

**/** is on sda2 with filesystem **ext4**

Did i make some mistake in kernel compilation?

Thanks.

Comment: check contents of /etc/fstab whether the line for sda1 has ext3 explicitely given as file system for sda1, instead of auto or ext4

Comment: How did you compile that kernel?

Comment: I compiled using "make menuconfig"